# How do you translate Sakai tool names and descriptions?

Tags: sakai

The names of several Sakai tools always appear in English even if I have set the Java default locale to Russian. 
I see this problem with the following tools in a new Sakai 10 build: Roster and Sign-up.

How do I translate these tool names and descriptions?

Comment: The question wording here is unclear. It should be reworded and clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Typically strings are collected into .properties files in the resource bundle of a Sakai tool.  The strings in these files must be carefully translated into a new language, named using the HTML language codes, pt-BR for Brazilian Portuguese, for example.  There are limits on the size of strings in properties, but most strings won't this limit.